# Tableau filter by column revenue where at least one meets a criteria?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I want to know if it is possible for tableau to filter out the revenue so that columns with even more than 2k in revenue can show up along with the items in the row of less than 2k for any given year with no null or zero rows showing up in the results.

I am using tableau web

[image]

[image]